# What is the meaning of the number $\frac{k!}{a_1!...a_n!}$?

Tags: combinatorics, taylor-expansion, multinomial-coefficients

It says that this is the number of $k$ tuples $(i_1,...,i_k), 1\leq i_k \leq n$ where the index $v$ appears exactly $a_v$ times $(v=1,..,n, a_1+...+a_n=k)$ Can someone give me an explaination how this formula comes to place?

Comment: Say you are counting the permutations of $\{A,A,A,B,B,C\}$.  You'd have $k=6$, $a_1=3, a_2=2,a_3=1$.

Comment: It is also the number of ways of taking a set of size $k$, and choosing a subset of size $a_1$, a subset of size $a_2$, etc... The wikipedia page has different interpretations and proofs:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem